# Can't Send the very first comment to planner task using microsoft graph api. Graph explorer says success but comment is not posted

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner

I am trying to send comments to plannertask but it is not posted. Basically if I had conversation thread id I can reply to that but to send the very first comment, I do not have conversation thread already existing.

I tried PATCHrequest from graph explorer to send the first comments. The response comes back as ok but I go back to that specific task, that I made patch request to, comment is not there.

I tried to PATCH `/planner/tasks/{taskid}` and `/planner/tasks/{taskId}/details` and I even tried POST. I have seen people talking about replying to the conversation thread id but nobody has talked about the very first comment.

Basically my code creates plans and tasks in it. some of the task I am trying to send a very first comment. In the beginning, conversation thread comes as `null` so I could not use that of course

[image]

Comment: There isn't a lot to go on here. What exactly are you sending when you receive the "ok"? Are you saying you're getting an `HTTP 200 (Okay)` rather than an `HTTP 201 (Created)` or `HTTP 204 (NoContent)`?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur thank you for responding let me upload some screen shots to elaborate.

Comment: I have a link to the image above. Sir, when I do post request to already existing conversation thread then it posts on the planner task using post request groups/{groupId}/threads/{threadId} but whereas when the task is initailly created and there is not  any existing thread id, I am not able to patch or post to create very first comment on the planner task. When I go mannually enter some comments though, I will get the threadId after that and I can reply to that from graph api. Problem here for me is that "conversationthreadId comes null at the beginning so couldnot reply or create the first"

Comment: Are you saying this _does_ work when there has been at least one other comment? That would surprise me since `post` isn't listed as a property of `task`.

Comment: What I meant was that If there was at least one comment there in the planner task then I can query in graph explorer to get the thread id and use post request  with this groups/{groupId}/threads/{threadId} api to reply to those comment. But when when task is created threadid comes null so there is no way to reply to any thread id. I was hoping pastch request to the task api would work to post comments it gives success like image above but does not post. Summary:  Post request to group api with thread id works but patch to task api to post comment with out thread id doesnot work

Comment: I am just wanting to send the first comment to planner task object once it is created. But it doesnot have any threadid to reply to.

Comment: This isn't supported and the Planner doesn't own the conversation. Conversations are owned by the Group.

Comment: Yes. Same problem here. When you add a new Task (whether by API or directly in the Planner app) the conversationThreadId is null. Comments on Tasks are Posts on the ConversationThread as denoted by the conversationThreadId on the Task.

You can add the first comment to the Task via the Planner app and after that you can add posts to that thread because the Planner app adds a conversationThreadId to the Task. 

BUT... it seems there is no way to START the thread on a Task via Graph. So you cannot add comments (posts) to it unless you manually add the first comment (thread) via Planner app!

Comment: @MarcLaFleur: Which is the best UserVoice forum to start a feature request for this please? Having to manually start a thread on a Task via the Planner app before one can add comments via the API seems like a huge (and very frustrating) gap to me. Thanks.

Comment: That's right @Murrah. This topic on the UserVoice forum would definitely get my one vote. I bet other developers are wanting this as well

Answer (score 2):

I believe I found an alternative solution to this problem. Since ConversationThreads are at the group level, before even creating a task, I created a conversation thread of that group with api
/groups/{id}/threads.

Now that you have a new Convothread laying around in the group, you can send the patch request for the task or even create a task with that conversation ThreadId.

In that way, you forced a particular task to have a conversationThreadId from the beginning. You can call that convoThreadiID to send as many comments as you want after that. All the comments sent to that convoThreadId would be posted on the task. Since graph api gives null for the threadId at the beginning of the task. I think this would be the best way to go. Let me know if I could explain this further to you.

Comment: Hi there Ashok, for this solution would it be possible to share out how this was accomplished?

Comment: Can you share the Graph calls you are using to:
Create the conversation thread in the group
Patch the task with the conversationId / conversationTheadId

Comment: POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/threads for creating thread                   {
    "planId": "xqQg5FS2LkCp935s-FIFm2QAFkHM",
    "bucketId": "hsOf2dhOJkqyYYZEtdzDe2QAIUCR",
    "title": "Update client list",
    "conversationThreadId": "the one you got from above"
    "assignments": {
      "fbab97d0-4932-4511-b675-204639209557": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.plannerAssignment",
        "orderHint": " !"
      }
    }
  }

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Ashok. I did consider that path but didn't actually try it. Since posting this I have pretty much given up using Planner for the reasons [outlined here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps-Formerly/Why-I-have-given-up-on-PowerApps-for-Planner/m-p/434525#M128729). Basically, way too many issues like this one wasting way too much time for no actual outcome.

Having said that, I am interested in your approach. I assumed that when I created the conversation it would appear in that group's UI somewhere, but that was an untested assumption on my part. I am not clear from your answer whether you have successfully done this yet. Any side-effects?

Thanks,
Murray

Comment: Hi there, yes I have worked on this process and my app highly depends on this process. As per the side effects, no side effects. I am sending comments as html body and comes the way it is expected. I will update this thread if I have problems in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Ashok. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to do it. My case may not exactly match your need but I am sharing it anyway.

I am assuming your planner belongs to a mail group, teams etc.

1- Create a conversation it the mail group.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{grouped}/conversations
```

This will return a conversation id and conversation_thread_id

2- Call task Api in planner to associate conversation_thread_id to the task

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks/{TASKID}
{

"conversationThreadId":"{conversation_thread_id}"
}
```

3- Additional benefit. Any time anyone replies to this thread in the email, the comments will be automatically added to the task

I am doing this in a logic app. In my flow, I create a planner task any time a new email lands in my group inbox. I also associate the original thread to the task. The rest, additional comment etc. just works

PROTIP: In logic apps connector, update task details does not provide "conversationThreadID" update, but you can switch to the code view and modify it manually. it works.